# jquery ajax request fails

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to web programming and I'm trying to select value for a selector box based on value selected in another selector box. Below is the jquery code snippet and php script for your reference. thanks for the help in advance.

jquery-ajax code

```
$(function(){
    $("#tier").change(function(){
    var formdata = {'tierval':document.getElementById("tier").value};
    alert("Selected Tier : "+document.getElementById("tier").value);
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/includes/getplayers.php",
          data: formdata,
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert("called getplayers.php");
                $("#opp").empty();
                $("#opp").html(data);
            },
            error:function()
            {
                alert('ajax failed');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

php script:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['tierval']))
{
    $tier = $_POST['tierval'];
}
$query = "select PlayerID,First_Name from GOFTEL.PLAYER where TierID = $tier";
$result = mysqli_query($pconn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
while($row)
{
echo '<option value=\"$row[PlayerID]\" > $row[First_Name] </option>';
}   
/* free result set */
$result->free();
/* close connection */
$pconn->close();
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: a jsfiddle would help get you a quick and accurate answer

Comment: I get the following php error where the passed data is not getting captured in the $_POST variable ."Undefined variable: tier in /var/www/html/includes/<filename> on line 17($query=...)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery consider the below:

```
var formdata = {'tierval':$("#tier").val};
alert("Selected Tier : "+$("#tier").val);
// or
console.log(formdata); // using the browser console
// or 
alert( this.value ); 
// or 
console.log($(this).val())
```

then you need to output something in the php script, so that `#opp` actually gets populated with the result, so

```
$query="select PlayerID,First_Name from GOFTEL.PLAYER where TierID = $tier";
$result=mysqli_query($pconn, $query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

print $row['First_Name'];
```

Then evaluate what you get in the console or alerts and go from there.

Comment: hi Alex,I get -Object {tierval: "2"} in the console and I have updated the rest of the php script in my question. I'm already outputting the html tags in the called php script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below code in php script

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo "<option value=" . $row[PlayerID]. ">" . $row[First_Name] . "</option>";

}
```